# How can I extract bookmarks(TOC) of a PDF file using NodeJS/ReactJS/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, reactjs, npm

Everyone must have seen that when you open a pdf in the browser or acrobat pdf reader a bookmarks tabs shows up just like this one
[image]

In case pdf does not have bookmarks the list will be empty. So I am looking to fetch these bookmarks from the pdf using nodejs/react/php.

Comment: https://medium.com/@csofiamsousa/creating-a-table-of-contents-with-pdf-js-4a4316472fff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the link to the [official docs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/module-pdfjsLib-PDFDocumentProxy.html#getDestinations) and its works I have tired it.

To be precise `getPageIndex` is the method you are looking for.